# Wpf Popup placement

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Is there any chance I can place popup next to an item from ListBox?
I use MVVM, list is bound to elements, and for some choosen elements I want to show popup next to the item.

I have list of elements and I want to show popup when I click on specified list element, but popup should be shown next to selected list item.

I tried something like this (it doesn't work):

```
    <Popup  IsOpen="{Binding Path=ShowPopup}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=List1, Path=SelectedItem}" Placement="Center">
        <TextBox Background="Red" Height="120" Text="Aaaaaa FUUUUUUUUUUUUU....."></TextBox>
    </Popup>
```

I don't want to use code behind, only xaml

Answer (score 7):

This will place a Popup to the right of the selected ListBoxItem

[image]

Example

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PopupListBoxItemTemplate" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid>
                <Popup Name="c_popup" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" >
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2.5">
                        <TextBlock Background="Wheat" Foreground="Black" Text="Aaaaaa FUUUUUUUUUUUUU....."/>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                <Setter TargetName="c_popup" Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="listBox"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource PopupListBoxItemTemplate}" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Excellent solution but I found a minor error. To get this working I had to change the Setter from {StaticResource ListBoxItemTemplate} to StaticResource PopupListBoxItemTemplate}.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your example doesn't work is simply because you are binding the placement target to a non-ui object.

```
PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=List1, Path=SelectedItem}"
```

SelectedItem in this case could be a model/view model that represents an item in your list, therefor is not a correct usage of the PlacementTarget property.

What you need is to set the PlacementTarget to the ItemContainer ([Dr. WPF explains](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/03/25/itemscontrol-i-is-for-item-container/)) and this is not possible without the help of "some" codes.

Now that you know the problem, there are a few ways to make your code work so i'll leave it up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to show the popup when the item is clicked, will this work for you:

```
<Popup  IsOpen="{Binding Path=ShowPopup}" Placement="Mouse">
     <TextBox Background="Red" Height="120" Text="Aaaaaa FUUUUUUUUUUUUU....."></TextBox>
 </Popup>
```